# Version mismatch for module @ionic-native/dialogs

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

I get the following error

Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /www/projects/project/node_modules/@ionic-native/dialogs/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3 …
when I run

$ ionic cordova build browser --prod
It’s working when I build without --prod

Env. info

$ ionic info
cli packages: (projects/project/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 6.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : browser 4.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v7.10.1
npm  : 4.2.0 
OS   : Linux 4.4
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

I need to publish new feature that uses Dialogs module by tomorrow so I would really appreciate any help…

thanks…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed @ionic-native/dialogs plugin and after that couldn't build my app for production anymore... Later I found out that npm installed the latest (incompatible) version of the plugin (4.4.0) but all other native plugins were at version 3.12.1... So I changed the new plugin version in the package.json file to 3.12.1 and installed it...
This fixed my problem...

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue with all native plugins used in my project.
All I did was uninstall and install the node modules for the corresponding plugins.

example:

```
$ npm uninstall --save @ionic-native/geolocation

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

Comment: this is correct but if you have older angular installed (in my case angular 4)  you first need to upgrade it to the lastest version (in my case version 5). I didn't have time to upgrade everything and fix potential bugs that could arise after the upgrade...